# Not sure why a JS error is happening

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have this page of US states:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/country.php?country_id=1&country_name=United%20States

if you click on any link for hiking in a state, as far as I can tell, the map on the right side loads.

But if you click on "Guam" for some reason that is the only place where the map does not load.  Any idea why that is happening? I see JS errors, but not sure why they are only happening on that page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/state.php?country_id=1&state_id=13&state_name=Guam&country_name=
Line: 1, Column: 23
Source Code:
initialize( 13.444304  144.793732 ); placeParkMarkers ( );
```

this error showed up
you need to separate the two values of co-ordinates with `,`

```
initialize( 13.444304, 144.793732 );
```